# Python 2.7 Py2exe with Tkinter and matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, py2exe

I'm trying to create an executable using py2exe for my Tkinter widget using python 2.7. This is my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import Tkinter
import py2exe
import numpy
import matplotlib
import scipy
import FileDialog



includes = ['scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx',
            'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation'
            ]

#dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll','libgobject-2.0-    0.dll','libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll']

setup(
    console=["home.py"]
    ,options={"py2exe":{'includes':includes
#                        ,'packages' : ['matplotlib','pytz']
 #                       ,'dll_excludes': dll_excludes
                        }
              }
    ,data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
    )
```

The executable compiles fine, but when I try to run home.exe from the dist folder it gives me this message.......and I have no idea how to fix it (I thought doing import FileDialog would do it):

```
File "matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.pyc", line 7, in <module>
File "six.pyc", line 194, in load_module
File "six.pyc", line 108, in _resolve
File "six.pyc", line 79, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named FileDialog
```

Thanks very much

Comment: have you imported FileDialog in home.py?

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you even search for `ImportError: No module named FileDialog` before posting this? There are multiple questions already in which you could have found you needed to `import FileDialog`.

Comment: Yes I did, which is why I had 'import FileDialog' in the setup.py file. I didn't realise it should have been in the target module itself

Comment: Ah I see. Drew my conclusions too quickly, sorry for that.